# Effect function failed to render on click of a button

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have this function in my Effect functions to make an API call to the backend:

```
   export function UpdateGroup(groupId: string, data: { name: string; desc: string; visibility: string, owners: string[], isApproved?: boolean, isRejected?: boolean, photo?: any }): Effect {
  // console.log(data)
  return async function (dispatch) {
    try {
      dispatch(loadingAction(true));
      api
        .update({
          resource: `siteGroups`,
          id: groupId,
          data: {
            name: data.name,
            desc: data.desc,
            visibility: data.visibility,
            owners: data.owners,
            isApproved: data.isApproved,
            isRejected: data.isRejected
            // photo: data.photo,
          },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          dispatch(FetchSiteGroup(groupId));
        })
        .catch((err) => new Error(err));
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      dispatch(loadingAction(false));
    }
  };
}
```

This is what the api.update method looks like:

```
  update(payload: { resource: string; id: string; data: any; query?: any }) {
    return http.put(`${payload.resource}/${payload.id}`, payload.data, {
      params: payload.query,
    });
  }
```

The Action Type:

```
export function fetchSiteGroupAction(group: ISiteGroup): ActionsType {
  return {
    type: ActionsEnum.FETCH_SITEGROUP,
    payload: group,
  };
}
```

The Reducer:

```
export function Reducer(state = initialState, action: ActionsType) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionsEnum.LOADING:
      return produce(state, (draft) => {
        draft.loading = action.payload;
      });
    case ActionsEnum.AUTH_SUCCESS:
      return produce(state, (draft) => {
        draft.token = action.payload.token;
        draft.user = action.payload.user;
        draft.isAdmin =
          action.payload.user.roles.find((r) => r === "admin") !== undefined;
        draft.loading = false;
      });
    case ActionsEnum.LOGOUT:
      return produce(state, (draft) => {
        draft.token = "";
        draft.loading = false;
      });
    case ActionsEnum.FETCH_MEMBERS:
      return produce(state, (draft) => {
        draft.members = action.payload;
        draft.loading = false;
      });
    case ActionsEnum.FETCH_SITEGROUP:
      return produce(state, (draft) => {
        draft.siteGroup = action.payload;
        // draft.loading = false;
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The function is called here when the Ok function is selected on the Modal card:

```
import { UpdateGroup } from "../store/Effects";

    

    <Modal
        title=""
        visible={isModalVisible}
        onOk={(e) => {
          // e.preventDefault();
          // ApproveGroup(groupInfo.groupId, { isApproved: true })
          // console.log(groupInfo);
          UpdateGroup(groupInfo.groupId, { name: groupInfo.displayName, desc: groupInfo.description, visibility: groupInfo.visibility, owners: groupInfo.owners, isApproved: true, isRejected: false })
          // approveGroup(groupInfo.groupId, groupInfo)
          handleCancel()
        }}
        onCancel={handleCancel}>
        This group <b>({groupInfo.displayName})</b> will now be approved
        </Modal>   <Modal
        title=""
        visible={isRejectModalVisible}
        onOk={(e) => {
          // ApproveGroup(groupId, { isApproved: true })
          e.preventDefault();
          // console.log("Rejected");
          UpdateGroup(groupInfo.groupId, { name: groupInfo.displayName, desc: groupInfo.description, visibility: groupInfo.visibility, owners: groupInfo.owners, isApproved: false, isRejected: true });
          setIsRejectModalVisible(false);
        }}
        onCancel={handleRejectCancel}>
    
        <p>This group <b style={{ color: "red" }}>({groupInfo.displayName})</b> will now be rejected
        </p>
     Comment: <Input.TextArea rows={4} />
</Modal>
```

The groupInfo content is gotten from a state which was updated from the

Comment: I see no react hooks being used in the code snippets, and the unformatted code is very difficult to read. Do you mind formatting it in a more standard way so it is easier to read? Can you also clarify what the issue is? React hooks don't render any content, that is what the component return is for.

Comment: The Effect function UpdateGroup dispatch action is not rendering when the function is called

Comment: Are you saying `UpdateGroup` is an action creator function and it isn't being dispatched to your (presumably) redux store? Have you verified/validated the modal's `onOk` callback is called? How is `UpdateGroup` imported and used in the component rendering the modals? Can you provide a more [Minimal, ***Complete***, and ***Reproducible***](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) properly formatted code example? I suspect you need to connect *some* component to your redux store, but we need more context how the two snippets relate.

Comment: @DrewReese, you are right on this. I have verified and confirm that the modal onOk is intact because the data I console.log before returning the dispatch function was logged.
I will update this question to reflect the lines where the functions were imported and the redux connection.

Comment: @DrewReese, I have updated the question.
Thanks for offering your help

Comment: Is `UpdateGroup` used directly from the import? Do you connect the component rendering the modal to your redux store? Just need to see *that* entire component really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say you just haven't wrapped your `UpdateGroup` action creator in a call to `dispatch`. This can be done in a couple ways.

## Using `connect` Higher Order Component

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { UpdateGroup } from "../store/Effects";

...

<Modal
  title=""
  visible={isModalVisible}
  onOk={(e) => {
    props.UpdateGroup(
      groupInfo.groupId,
      {
        name: groupInfo.displayName,
        desc: groupInfo.description,
        visibility: groupInfo.visibility,
        owners: groupInfo.owners,
        isApproved: true,
        isRejected: false,
      },
    );
    handleCancel()
  }}
  onCancel={handleCancel}
>

...

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  UpdateGroup,
};

export connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ComponentWithModal);
```

## Using `useDispatch` react hook

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { UpdateGroup } from "../store/Effects";

...

const dispatch = useDispatch();

<Modal
  title=""
  visible={isModalVisible}
  onOk={(e) => {
    dispatch(
      UpdateGroup(
        groupInfo.groupId,
        {
          name: groupInfo.displayName,
          desc: groupInfo.description,
          visibility: groupInfo.visibility,
          owners: groupInfo.owners,
          isApproved: true,
          isRejected: false,
        },
      ),
    );
    handleCancel();
  }}
  onCancel={handleCancel}
>

...

export ComponentWithModal;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was not wrapping the update action in a dispatch.